# Squaring 4 Buttons with getResources().getIdentifier

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make 4 Buttons in a Table layout square.

The Buttons look like that (id is counting up to 4):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_selector"
        android:text="Button1" />
```

Everything looks fine so far.
Now I want to get the witdh of each Button and set that value as its height.

My code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

        String buttonID = "button" + i;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(resID);
        int width = b.getWidth();
        b.setHeight(width);
    }

}
```

But that crashes... WHY?

Please help me.

Comment: Please, provide exception trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try and make your button as below

```
Button[] buttons; 
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
{
 String buttonID = "button" + (i+1);

 int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
 buttons[i] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
 //set your height and width as you are doing.
}
```

hope it works...

Comment: ...but i can't use findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid) in a for-loop with button1, button2, button3 and button4.

Comment: can you post your log output...here